# How can I link image id's associated with a post id into a gallery?

Tags: php

I am creating a post page for user uploaded posts that will show images the user uploads along with their written information.

My specific issue is how can I link the specific image id's associated with that post so only those images that belong with the post will show up rather than all the images in the folder? I need to get all the `img_id` linked to each post's `post_id`.

So if a post with the post with a `post_id` of "1" is associated with the `img_id`s 1 through 4 and any subsequent `img_id`s belong to other `post_id`s, I want to display only those `img_id`

Here is my current HTML/PHP to show the images on the post.php page:

```
<?php
  $files=scandir("admin/images");
  ?>

<div class="carousel-inner">

          <?php
            $i = 0;
            for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++):
          ?>

          <div class="item <?php echo $i == 0 ? 'active': '';  ?>" align="center">
            <img src="admin/images/<?php echo $files[$a];?>">
          </div>

          <?php
            $i++;
            endfor;
          ?>
        </div>
```

I've tried replacing the

```
            <img src="admin/images/<?php echo $files[$a];?>">
```

with

```
       <?php 
        $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id' ";
        $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
        if($q2->num_rows>0){ 
          while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object());
          echo "<img src='admin/images/".$row->img_id."' width='100%' height='100%' >";
          }
        ?>
```

But I keep getting the *Undefined property: stdClass::$img_id* error.

Here is my `images` table for reference just in case anyone wants to have a look at it:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `img_path` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `img_type` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `img_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Your missing `img_id` in the query, so its not going to be returned.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ouh, I missed that.

Comment: Also its `image_id` in the database schema :/

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner multiple problems including SQLi...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone *Sigh*, don't I know it. Thanks

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for pointing that out for me! I completely missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, get rid of the semi-colon in this line:

```
while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()); // <<<
```

it ends the statement, dead in its tracks and cannot reference the data being echo'd on the next line.

- Use [`mysqli_error($db)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) on the query.

You're also using two different variables here for

`while ($imrow`, then using `$row->img_id` later on; they need to match.

Use PHP's error reporting for capturing errors like this:

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Side note: Remember to add an additional closing `}` brace for the opening brace `{` to be added to the `while` loop.

---

**Edit/kudos:**

As [Lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) spotted (in comments), you are missing the `img_id` in the query. Yet, you need to use the `image_id` as a reference.

---

Footnotes:

Do protect yourself against an possible [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by using a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at this for awhile so I didn't notice the syntax errors like the `$imrow` and `$row` thing. The images are now displaying properly, but they're showing up stacked in one frame of the carousel rather than each image showing up individually when the next or previous button is pressed. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: `<?php 
            $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id'";
            $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
            if($q2->num_rows>0){
              while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()){
              echo "<img src='admin/images/".$imrow->img_name."' width='auto' height='auto'>";
            }
          }
            ?>`

Comment: @Vel you're welcome. Now as for the images being stacked, that would be something else entirely and would be an HTML / CSS based question. So, you'd need to ask a new question about that.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into that for that issue. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to have been of help @Vel . Laurence had something to do with this, so maybe you'd like to say thanks to him also (in an `@` ping to him). *Cheers*

Comment: Of course! Thanks @LawrenceCherone for spotting that error I made!

Comment: @Vel :-) am not sure if he did get pinged here being in an answer, that I never did know how that quite works here. I'll see if I can find something about it on meta. Usually people get pinged in the present thread which he isn't part of here, but he is under your post though.

Comment: Oh okay haha. I am unfamiliar with pinging people on here, so I wasn't quite sure how that worked either.